# Setting the service URL at runtime

Tags: c#, asmx, app-config

When I am adding the "Web Reference" we are giving the address to the asmx page to visual studio.

How Can I set this at run time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the Url property of the object before you call any of the service methods:

```
YourService service = new YourService();
service.Url = "http://some.other.url/";

// Now you're ready to call your service method
service.SomeUsefulMethod();
```

Answer (score 6):

I would have upvoted one of the other answers - they're almost correct.

```
using (YourService service = new YourService())
{
    service.Url = "http://some.other.url/"; 

    // Now you're ready to call your service method 
    service.SomeUsefulMethod(); 
}
```

If a using block is not used, and an exception is thrown, then resources like network connections can be leaked.

Answer (score 2):

```
YourWebService service = new YourWebService();
service.Url = "http://www.example.com/YourWebService.asmx";
service.CallMethod();
```