# In winforms, how do I dynamically change the url of my web reference?

Tags: winforms, asmx, webservice-client, web-reference

I have 2 websites with an identical web service.  For web service `SampleService`, I would like to know how to choose which web server to choose from.

- **Web service**: "SampleService"
- **Web reference**: "SampleWebReference"

Web service url:

- **Site 1**: http://www.samplesite.com
- **Site 2**: http://www2.samplesite.com

Q: How do I programmatically change which site the web reference references based on user selection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the properties of a WebReference in run-time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211510/is-it-possible-to-change-the-properties-of-a-webreference-in-run-time)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASMX: setting the website at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997885/asmx-setting-the-website-at-runtime)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on your web service and in the properties window set the URL behaviour to `Dynamic`.

Then to set the url in code:

```
SampleWebReference reference = new SampleWebReference();
reference.Url = "http://www2.samplesite.com";
```