# how to change the web service link dynamically?

Tags: web-services, asmx

As we are working locally so our service link is: http://localhost:8012/webservice.asmx

When we deploy the webservice on our service, we have to remove the local web service and then add the web service link again for example: http://test.com/webservice.asmx.

It is not convenient to remove the web service reference and add it again. Is there any elegant solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASMX: setting the website at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997885/asmx-setting-the-website-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YourService service = new YourService();
service.Url = "http://some.other.url/";
```