# How to change the Web Reference URL through TextBox

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdl, web-reference, reportserver

I am creating a project to download all RDLs deployed on the ReportServer.

I have found this article on Codeproject and it is working fine.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339744/SSRS-Downloading-RDL-Files

Now what I'm trying to do is to add a textbox on the designer which the user will provide the reportserver URL

```
http://servername/reportserver
```

I found a related question here:
[How to change Location(Url) of a Web Service and Update Web Reference programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321744/how-to-change-locationurl-of-a-web-service-and-update-web-reference-programmat?answertab=votes#tab-top)

but I can't get the MyApi stated on the topic.

To summarize, my question is how to change the "Web Reference URL" of a web service through URL value on the textbox field provided by the user

EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 2012!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my search regarding the concern mislead me to change app.config, change Settings.Designer.cs, etc.

but the solution is to add a single line.

```
ssrsWebService.ReportingService2010 rs = new ssrsWebService.ReportingService2010();
rs.Url = ReportServerURLTxt.Text + "/ReportService2010.asmx";
```

i feel so dumb not checking on the available settings on the report service.